# How to automatically scroll LazyColumn when the keyboard goes up or down in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column, android-compose

I am making a chatting app with android compose.

Usually, when you scroll freely within the chat window and press the text input window to bring up the keyboard, the chat at the bottom of the screen naturally moves up.

I tried to implement it naturally, but it didn't work out well.

I tried using `rememberLazyListState()` to input `scrollOffset` using `listState.scrollToItem` or `listState.animationScrollToItem`, but it feels quite unnatural.

How can we implement natural LazyColumn scrolling?

**[EDIT]**
I think additional explanation is needed, so I'll attach a photo.
[image]
Can you see the chat slightly overlapping the input window like that before the keyboard comes up?
[image]

Even when the keyboard comes up, can you see that the chat is still uploaded, overlapping with the input window?

This is how I want it. I want the last chat I was viewing to scroll on the screen even if the keyboard is raised or lowered.
The photo was taken from Telegram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For original setting of LazyColumn, when LazyColumn's viewport size changed, Compose will try to conserve top messages visible on view.

For some special cases like chat app, when LazyColumn's viewport size changed and you want to make bottom messages visible, you can use field `reverseLayout`

```
                 LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    reverseLayout = true,
                    state = lazyListState
                ) {
                    ...
                }
```

Of course you have to change some of logic to fit your business, but this layout is the best fit for Chat app.

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I ask one more thing? When ```reverseLayout=true``` is set, LazyColumn's items are automatically pushed up every time a new message arrives. Do you know how to stop this?

Comment: I guess you keep key null in items(key = null) right? When you use null key compose doesnt know how to remain view port when data change, so it view change. So change it to some thing like your data id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Modifier.imePadding() When the keyboard appears, it will push the content up, including your LazyColumn.

```
@Composable
fun ChatScreen() {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val messages = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }
    var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

    // Add a dummy list of messages for demonstration
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        repeat(50) { index ->
            messages.add("Message $index")
        }
    }

    // Scroll to the bottom of the list when the keyboard appears
    LaunchedEffect(keyboardController?.isVisible) {
        if (keyboardController?.isVisible == true) {
            listState.animateScrollToItem(messages.size - 1)
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .imePadding() // Adjust padding based on the IME
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            reverseLayout = true // Start from the bottom
        ) {
            items(messages) { message ->
                Text(
                    text = message,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                )
            }
        }

        BasicTextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = { textFieldValue = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(8.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply

First of all, I don't think you understood the intent of my question.
Using ```listState.animateScrollToItem(messages.size - 1)``` means you want to scroll to the most recent message.
What I mean is that when the keyboard comes up, the last message seen on the **screen** comes up naturally.
Conversely, when the keyboard goes down, the last message shown on the **screen** goes down naturally.

I want the focus to be on the last message visible on the **screen**, rather than the last message in the message list.

Comment: I have attached a photo for additional explanation, but if you do not understand my explanation, please refer to it.